# How to call this method in swift 3.0?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Here I have an Objective - C Method:

```
+(void)postSaveCoinOrder:(OrderSaveCoinOrderRequestModel *)model returnInfo:(void(^)(OrderSaveCoinOrderResponseModel* resModel))retMode;
```

and I want call it in Swift file. tried many times but don't work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The logic: The `+` indicates its a class method and not a instance one. `model` is a simple param. and the `(void(^)(some stuff))` is called a block, which in Swift is translated as a closure. Once you understood that, it should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
let request = OrderSaveCoinOrderRequestModel.init()
CLASS_NAME.postSaveCoinOrder(request) { (response) in

}
```

`CLASS_NAME` is the name of the class where `postSaveCoinOrder` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add a bridge file in your project?

If so, code like this...

```
let model = OrderSaveCoinOrderRequestModel()
CLASSNAME.postSaveCoinOrder(model: model, returnInfo: {
    (retModel: OrderSaveCoinOrderRequestModel) -> () in
    ...
})
```

I think this will be more detailed.